# Can we use gatling or Jmeter to perform operations such as input text, click on element, select dropdown?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, gatling

Can we perform **functional-load** testing using gatling or jmeter?

By Functional load testing I mean to perform certain operations on web application. User performs operations such as

- Clicking on link
- Entering text into a combo box (textbox + Dropdown)
- Enter text into multiple textboxes
- And many other operations

I want to load web app with **N** number of users to identify the point where the application breaks.

I have tried using Selenium Webdriver with TestNG and its [invocationCount](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#annotations) and thread-pool-size. This opens 100's of browsers which degrades the performance of the systems on which I am running the tests.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You cannot inject 100 browser instances. Here is the formula to calculate how many threads you can run in JMeter + Selenium WDS. `C = B + 1` where C = Number of Cores of the host running the test N = Number of Browser (threads). Your objective is to measure client-side performance; there is no point in running 100+ threads. Execute your test for less number of threads (in non-GUI mode); I prefer to execute UI tests with 1 thread. This will simulate real world scenario. Hope this helps.

Comment: Can I combine Selenium Webdriver tests with Jmeter?

Comment: Yes You can combine. But run with 1 user.

Comment: That would be useful as I would not be able to generate enough load on the web application

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can create your tests using selenium and integrate it with Jmeter to control you load

Please find below link for how to integrate selenium with Jmeter

https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler

Comment: Blazemeter is not free.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are looking for a free tool to run multiple webdriver tests concurrently and at load? If so I am not aware of any free tools that can scale to hurdreds or thousands of fully headed brower sessions but there are paid tools out there. If you are interested let me know and I will share.